# Rails startup performance: how to trace and debug

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, performance, passenger

Our Rails 3.2.8 app is taking around 30 seconds to load after restarting, with similar load time for `rails console`. This is on an Amazon EC2 `m1.small` instance with Ubuntu 11, 64-bits.  The server seems perfectly suitable under load (we have several).  The startup time, which effectively occurs only after a deploy is a problem.

Is there a way to get a timed trace of what is loading as the Rails instance loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a pretty good walkthrough by adding `pry` and `pry-nav` to your Gemfile

```
# Gemfile
gem 'pry'
gem 'pry-nav'
```

Once this is in place, you can simply add `binding.pry` to the top of one of the files loaded early on, such as `environment.rb` or `boot.rb`. (This assumes that you're running on localhost:3000, otherwise things get more complicated.) Restart your app and you should be placed into a pry session. Us `next` to step through each line of code your app hits on startup! You can add multiple `binding.pry` lines throughout your code if you want to jump from one to the other, just type `exit` to move to the next one.

This will not benchmark your app, but it will allow you to step through what your app is doing, which might in itself allow you to actually experience what is taking so long.

Comment: This isn't that useful, because Ruby encourages so much metaprogramming, that you have to step through hundreds, maybe thousands of calls, to get to meaningful information